# React app: npm run build throws "sh: cross-env: command not found" even after running npm i

Tags: npm, node-modules

I have been unable to run the command `npm run build` unsuccessfully, I get the following issue:

```
> @myer-online/frontend@1.0.0 build /Users/surbhimidha/myer-online
> cross-env NODE_ENV=production next build

sh: cross-env: command not found
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! @myer-online/frontend@1.0.0 build: `cross-env NODE_ENV=production next build`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @myer-online/frontend@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/surbhimidha/.npm/_logs/2021-02-10T08_06_42_019Z-debug.log
```

I am using the following versions of node and npm:
npm: 6.14.8
node: 14.13.1

I have tried to delete node modules and run `npm i` but still I get the above error when I run `npm run build`

I noticed that cross-env is not present under /node_modules/.bin

Please help!

Comment: Is it listed as dependency in your package.json?

Comment: Yes, it is there under scripts: ```"build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production next build",```

Comment: Even ```"cross-env": "^6.0.3",``` is there under devDependencies. When I run `npm i` I do not get any error, but this package and other packages like ` "eslint": "^7.13.0",` do not get installed.

Comment: Got any solution? me too facing same issue in "web pack vue"